# Use Escape Letter With Variable in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am update the record using trigger.

Am tried

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_trg_sales2()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$  declare

 xNarr text='';

 select name into xNarr from t1 where id =1;

 update t2 set narration =E narration || case when narration ='' then  xNarr else 
'\n' || xNarr end where id=1

return null;
 end; 
 $BODY$
```

above procedure show error.

How to use `escape character` in this update query using variable?
 How to use escape character with variable?. Don't suggest with out variable using escape character.

Am using **postgresql 9.1**

**EDIT**

I get information form some command so i update like this in my trigger

```
update t2 set narration =narration || case when narration ='' then  xNarr else 
    quote_literal('\n') || xNarr end where id=1
```

Now it show in table in two lines but its end and start with '.

like

```
narration

 this is first'
 'this is second
```

how to store with out single qutoation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in  [String Constants with C-style Escapes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE), the strings that contain escape sequences with backslashes must start with `E` as in `E'line1\nline2'` or `E'\n'` for a newline alone.

This `E` syntax has become mandatory since PostgreSQL 9.1 in its default configuration  regarding `standard_conforming_strings`, as warned in the doc at the same place:

> If the configuration parameter standard_conforming_strings is off,
>   then PostgreSQL recognizes backslash escapes in both regular and
>   escape string constants. However, as of PostgreSQL 9.1, the default is
>   on, meaning that backslash escapes are recognized only in escape
>   string constants.
>   This behavior is more standards-compliant, but might break
>   applications which rely on the historical behavior, where backslash
>   escapes were always recognized

The `quote_literal` function is meant to build SQL statements programmatically before they're fed to the SQL interpreter, that's why its results includes single quotes. This function is not necessary and not helpful for your use case.